# Is possible to ask GCM server unable to push notification to expired/obsolete registration id?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm develop an android application use GCM, when I upgrade app version, I must register GCM registration id again, and GCM server return new registration. But when push a notification to both old registration id and new registration id, GCM accept all of those. GCM will returns response "send successfully" with message include newest registration id.

```
{"multicast_id":4727651484309285125,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,"results":[{"registration_id":"APA91bEVF3NWBSdTy9JuEAQCs3DEg-uLYR1F5j7v4_vmbW0ccsSDpEMLRF4SPoo2U4Ikqfn9oCyv4OYZnW6sUSBo_AjL6-07Ex3NX8vYgK0SSr6JriP4wkHF0a-WG2vRV5IAsg3gn7pY","message_id":"0:1445568030699378%9fffe997f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Is possible to ask GCM disable old registration, so any attempt to push message to old registration id will be rejected.
I want to be able to push notification to newest registration only.
Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: As I know gcm returns canonical id if there are several registration ids for one device, so your backend server should replace old registration id by canonical. In this case you will store new Ids only. More here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases GCM will still send messages to tokens that should no longer be used. When you send a message and receive a canonical ID, which is what the [registration_id](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) in results is. You should update your server side list of tokens by removing the token that resulted in a canonical ID in the response, using the canonical ID instead.